# CSS layout issue  with three boxes floating inside a container, not 'touching'

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm creating a layout using HTML. I have a problem with three boxes floating inside a container, I don't want them touching.

Here is my CSS code:

```
/************************** Portfolio Section ***********************************/

#portfolio-container 
{
background: darkgreen;
height: 100px;
}

#portfolio1
{
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 330px
}

#portfolio2
{
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 100px;
    width: 330px
}

#portfolio3
{
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 330px
}

#main-content 
{
background: green;
height: 100px;
}
```

Okay, so I want the portfolio1, 2 and 3 to be inside the portfolio container. here is the HTML

```
<div id="portfolio-container">
    portfolio-container
</div>

<div id="portfolio1">portfolio 1</div>

<div id="portfolio2">portfolio 2</div>

<div id="portfolio3">portfolio 3</div>

<div id="main-content">
    main-content
</div>
```

I know this is probably a little basic, but I'm struggling to find specific info on this problem. Should I be using `li` to make a list or could I do something fancy in the CSS?

Thanks for the help. Some reading material is always welcome if you know of useful tutorials?

Comment: Floating? Theres no float tag on the containers. Also you should actually put portfolio1, portfolio2 and portfolio3 inside the portfolio-container tag

Comment: 'i don't want them touching', what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2):

You have Write html like this

```
<div id="portfolio-container">
<div id="portfolio1">portfolio 1</div>
<div id="portfolio2">portfolio 2</div>
<div id="portfolio3">portfolio 3</div>
</div>
```

and css like

```
#portfolio-container 
{
background: darkgreen;
height: 100px;
width:1000px;
float:left;
}

#portfolio1
{
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 330px;
float:left;
}

#portfolio2
{
    background: lightgreen;
    height: 100px;
    width: 330px;
float:left;
}

#portfolio3
{
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    width: 330px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: @Sonal I dont think that satisfies his "not toucing " case by any means.

Comment: Its okay, the "not touching" part i think is just a matter of editing the margins between them. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to float your DIVs.

I have made a code example on how to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/g5xCk/

Answer (score 1):

I dont get you, you want them inside with the same height but with an overflow or side by side positioning? Be specific.

**One below the other** : http://jsfiddle.net/qBwC4/4/

**Side By Side** : http://jsfiddle.net/gVd8F/1/

Note : Float is quite a misleading term.